# What are enclosures in elfeed?

Tags: elfeed

The term is used many times here
https://github.com/oystersauce8/elfeed/blob/master/elfeed-show.el

Googled it:
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=elisp%3A+what+are+enclosures+in+elisp&t=h_&ia=web
not much info actually.

Comment: It looks like a word made up by the author of the code. I guess it refers to some data structure elfeed uses to "enclose" information about entries.

Comment: If and when someone provides an answer to this, someone please change the tags. Maybe some elfeed user will answer this; if not, you're probably better off asking the elfeed maintainer. I didn't see any description of "enclosure" in the code, scanning it briefly.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked it up myself when wondering why my podcasts came through with links to the audio on my rss reader on my phone, but the links were nowhere present in elfeed. I found the explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_enclosure . The elfeed author was not, in fact, making up terms. In short, the enclosure to an RSS item is analogous to an attachment to an email, except for the key difference that the enclosure is only a hyperlink (ie to the mp3) and not the actual file. The actual data is usually not included on RSS links.